# Ajax to php and then php to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have index.php with html form, user enters data, submits form (with ajax/jquery), server calls REST service with form params, parses response and sends result (array as json) to javascript on that same index.php. The part that **is not working in my code is sending response back to javascript.** It sends hardcoded array json for testing purpose but fails with dinamic response from REST. REST itself is ok and return correct data with var_dump().

index.php

```
<?php

//index.php

...

//submiting form

<script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript" >

    function submitForm()
    {
       $("#gl_forma").submit();
    }

</script>

...

if(!empty($params['arg1']) )
{
    $result = call_rest_service($connection, $params);//its ok

    //send POST to ajax.php that is just for echoing to javascript
    $response = sendPost('http://127.0.0.1/mysite/ajax.php', $result);
}
//function to send POST
function sendPost($url, $data)
{   
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode($data),// here encodes it
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
        "Accept: application/json\r\n"
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    $result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
    return $response = json_decode($result);        
}

...

<script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript" >
//get back data from php to js

//#search_button the same button that submited form

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#search_button').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data: 'id=testdata',
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));//alerts the hardcoded array for testing, but wont real results
          },
          });
    });
});
 </script>
```

ajax.php - just for echoing results to javascript

```
<?php

    //ajax.php

    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');//catch POST
    $_REQUEST = array();    
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND );//it writes, just for debuging...
    echo $data;//its encoded already
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#search_button').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data: 'id=testdata',
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false
          }).done(function( result ) {
               alert(JSON.stringify(result));//alerts the hardcoded array for testing, but wont real results
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: Might want to clarify how to parse the form into the data parameter.